# Incomplete CSV to JSON via FTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

Got some code that connects to an FTP server, converts the data to CSV and stores it in an array that will be later be used to update a database.

I'm dealing with many large CSV files and when accessing from FTP, they return incomplete!
I output the array length, and it's different every time (but usually close to the full length)

Removing `.end()` does not change the result, so it's not disconnecting early...

Downloading the CSV files manually (not an option expt. for dev) does result in the full file being read.

Any ideas appreciated, cheers :)

Here is the code

```
var FTPClient = require('ftp');
var c = new FTPClient();
var csv = require("csvtojson");

c.connect({
    host: '****',
    user: '****',
    password: '****',
    debug: console.log,
});

dataArray = []
c.on('ready', function() {
    c.get('/file.csv', function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;
        stream.once('close', function() {
            console.log(dataArray.length)
            c.end();
        });
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
            csv({
                    noheader: false,
                    headers: ["Header1", "Header2", ]
                })
                .fromString(chunk.toString())
                .subscribe(function(jsonObj) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        dataArray.push(jsonObj)
                        resolve()
                    })
                })
                .on("end", function() {
                    console.log("done");
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use this for streaming and parsing

```
const PromiseFtp = require('promise-ftp'),
    ftp = new PromiseFtp();
const csv = require("csvtojson");

var jsonArray = []
var credentails = {
    host: '*****',
    user: '*****',
    password: '*****',
}
var csvFile = {
    formatA: ['filesA.csv'],
    formatB: ['filesB.csv'],
    formatC: ['filesC.csv']
}

async function fptUpdate(file) {
    await ftp.connect(credentails).then(function() {
        return ftp.get(file);
    }).then(function(stream) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            stream.pipe(csv(headers))
                .on('data', (data) => {
                    let string = data.toString('utf8')
                    let json = JSON.parse(string)
                    jsonArray.push(json);
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    resolve()
                });
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return ftp.end();
    });
}

async function start() {
    for (const file of csvFiles) {
        await fptUpdate(file)
        console.log(jsonArray.length)
        jsonArray = []
        console.log('Processed file: ' + file)
    }
}
start()
```